# uwp CalendarDatePicker set date format

Tags: win-universal-app

I'm trying to set a date format for the CalendarDatePicker for globalisation purposes. I tried this:

```
endDate = (FindName("cdpEnd") as CalendarDatePicker);
endDate.DateFormat = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
endDate.Date = workObject.EndCal;
```

But it gave me the following exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: The parameter is incorrect.

formatTemplate
   at Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.CalendarDatePicker.put_DateFormat(String value)
   at App1.PageWorkObject.rootGrid_Loaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

I checked the value I had set and it looked normal to me: `"M/d/yyyy"`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

When you use a [CalendarDatePicker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendardatepicker.aspx), the string content of the `TextBox` portion of it is created by a [DateTimeFormatter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.globalization.datetimeformatting.datetimeformatter.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2).

`"M/d/yyyy"` seems to be normal, but

> Important  You can't arbitrarily combine components and necessarily obtain a valid template. The only valid templates are those defined by the provided grammar.

If you read refer to the `DateTimeFormatter` class, you will find there is no format like `"M/d/yyyy"`, for the same format like `"M/d/yyyy"`, I think it should be like this:

```
endDate.DateFormat = "{month.integer}‎/‎{day.integer}‎/‎{year.full}";
```

Comment: Is there any way to fix this for all globalisation? i.e. europe?

Comment: @RobinDijkhof, I think the way to do this can be using data binding to bind the `DateFormat` property of `CalendarDatePicker`, and then according to the region select the different format.